# Delegate methods no longer called after converting to use Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I've converted an app I'm writing to ios 5 and then using the inbuilt tool I converted it to use Automatic Reference Counting. There were no problems with ios 5 but after ARC conversion most of my delegate calls don't seem to be working. For example I have a subclass of UITableViewController with a .h file that looks like:

```
@interface UITableVCSubclass : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, ... >
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
...
@end
```

The Table View Delegate method tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: no longer gets called when I select a row of the table. If checked that self.tableview.delegate == self, which it does. Any ideas why this has stopped working?

Comment: Can you provide your implementation (if there is one) of the UITableViewDelegate method: **-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;**

Comment: originally there wasn't a willSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. I added the following just to see if it would get called:
'- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"willSelectRowAtIndexPath called");
    return nil;
}'
 . . . it's not getting called.

Comment: Is the **tableView.delegate => self** connection being defined programmatically, or in Interface Builder?

Comment: Did you use the ARC conversion tool, or did you change the classes yourself?

Comment: I'm not using interface builder and tableView.delegate => self is done automatically by the UITableViewController class. I used the ARC conversion tool.

Comment: possible dupe of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852308/delegate-method-wont-fire-is-null-using-arc

Comment: I think you should show us the UITableVCSubclass.m file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a good reference so hopefully this will help someone else.  My working project didn't work after running the ARC refactoring doohickey.  The view controller for my UITableView was being created on the fly and pushed without saving a reference, which is not something the conversion process looks for.

ARC was releasing the vc when it fell out of scope, so the view was visible but its delegate was gone.  To fix it I added a strong property to the super to hold a reference to the new view controller and then I started receiving events again.

Changed from this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = 
    [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

To using the new property:

```
self.myViewController = 
    [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```