# Delegate method won't fire (is null). Using ARC

Tags: ios, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having trouble getting my delegate method to fire. I have the following code:

```
@class Location;
@protocol LocationDelegate
- (void)location:(Location*)location foundLocation:(CLLocation*)location;
- (void)location:(Location*)location failedToLocateUserWithError:(NSError*)error;
@end 

@interface Location : NSObject {
    __unsafe_unretained id <LocationDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <LocationDelegate> delegate;

@end

...
@implementation Location

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)startUpdatingLocation {
    NSLog(@"%@", delegate); // prints '(null)'
    ...

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"%@", delegate); // prints '(null)'
    [delegate location:self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

@end
```

Used to work fine for other projects, so wondering if it has to do with ARC? The object that allocates `Location` does conform to `LocationDelegate`. I am also setting the delegate to self. But the delegate method just isn't firing, and if I output it, it's null.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From just the code you've pasted here, I don't see *anything* that is holding on to your delegate (a retained reference).

Everything you've pasted specifically shows you going out of your way to not have the delegate retained by this code.

If thats how you want it to be, then you better be sure it's been retained elsewhere - otherwise ARC will correctly conclude that since no one has a strong (retained) reference to the delegate, that it's safe (and proper) to release it.

> The object that allocates Location does conform to LocationDelegate. I
>   am also setting the delegate to self.

And who has a strong reference to that object?

Comment: I've tried changing it to (nonatomic, strong) and no unsafe_unretained, but still nothing.

Comment: Get rid of the ivar. On lines where you're referencing the delegate (like this one: `[delegate location....`) use `self.delegate` instead.

Comment: After the assignment, add a watch in the debugger, then you'll see when it goes to nil.

Comment: You said you were assigning the delegate property at some point. Put a breakpoint on that line. Step over it. Then add a watch in the debugger.

Comment: In the class I alloc `Location` in, I am setting `location.delegate = self;`

Comment: Should I copy & paste my last suggestion again then? **Put a breakpoint on that line. Step over it. Then add a watch in the debugger.**

Comment: I agree with @Steve. It looks like wherever you're allocating the delegate object, you're not retaining it. So you may set it successfully, but it's deallocated by the time your delegate methods are fired. Why don't you post the code where create the delegate object and assign it?

Comment: Update. I confirmed another class with a delegate was working fine. Code was identical except names. I created another class, copied the exact lines of code for the Location delegate over and it worked perfectly, very strange and very frustrating. Not sure what the heck was going on. But thanks for all your helps regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are allocating `Location` have you assigned the delegate?
Eg: 
`Location *location = [[Location alloc] init];
location.delegate = self;`

Comment: He specifically said he was: `I am also setting the delegate to self.`

Comment: Try adding <NSObject> after @protocol LocationDelegate